# accuracy for 1D CNN model is very low

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I tried to build 1D CNN model to DNA mutation classification I built the model and it works correctly but I get test data with low accuracy I have dataset like the picture bellow[image: 1]

and this is my model

```
vocab_size = 100
embedding_dim = 150
max_len = 90
X_train = pad_sequences(X_train,padding ='post', maxlen = max_len)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test,padding ='post', maxlen = max_len)
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_dim,input_length = max_len))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, 7, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs = 10, verbose = False,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),batch_size = 10)
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train,y_train, verbose = False)
accuracy = accuracy*100
print("training accuracy = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
loss,accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test, verbose = False)
accuracy = accuracy*100
print("test accuracy = {:.2f}".format(accuracy))
```

my input is ['sequence','normal','mutated','position']
and target column is ['class'] column
so what is the problem with my test accuracy.

**Edit:**
I tried to change percent of test data in train_test_split function and increased percent of test data to avoid overfitting but test accuracy still low

Comment: Don't use a sigmoid in the last `Dense` layer when you've used `relu` in the upper layers. This could lead to fully saturated firings of the neurons ( using `sigmoid` ). Instead, try setting `units=2` in the last `Dense` layer and change the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: but I need output with shape (,1) so I can't set ```units=2``` and I used 'binary_crossentropy' because I need output is 0 or 1 only

Comment: and I changed 'sigmoid' function accuracy decreased

Comment: @mohamedhossam Is the validation/training accuracy high and the test accuracy low?

Comment: @Wanderer yes there is overfitting and it didn't resolve by increasing test data

Comment: To know if your model is overfitting, the easiest way is to finish your training and then evaluate your model on your dataset’s test split. If the results are much worse than the training accuracy, that’s a good indicator of overfitting. some resources here [overfit and underfit](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit)

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods that you can employ to generalize your model and improve test accuracy:

1- check to see if your datasets are unbalanced or not. unbalancing datasets means that the size of data in each class has substantially different.

2- you can use the data/image augmentation technique to increase the size of datasets or balance classes size.

3- Doing Hyperparameter optimization, change optimizer types, batch_size, learning rate and other hyperparameters to find the optimum ones.

4- in some cases using other functions for loss and accuracy can be helpful.